# Moving git branch to another local repo

Tags: git

I have two git repositories at `/trees/repo` and `/trees/repo_recovered`.  The recovered version was manually copied over from a dying computer.  There is one un-pushed branch in this repo that I would like to move to `/trees/repo`.  I *could* push this branch to the remote and then pull it down into the new repo, but I would prefer not to share this work yet.

How can I copy a branch (and all it's history) across the filesystem?

Comment: Add `/trees/repo_recovered` as a remote to `/trees/repo` and then fetch a branch from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add another remote repository which just happens to be locally available on your file system.

```
git remote add recovered /trees/repo_recovered
git fetch recovered
```

Comment: Got it, simple!  It brings along all the other working branches I had, but I can manually clean out that stuff.

Comment: You could also do it the other way around, adding the new repository to the recovered one and then push only the branch you are interested in transferring. But it doesn’t really matter much :)